# How does Gnome (Cinnamon) find the icon for an executable binary?

Tags: linux, icons, gnome, cinnamon

I recently installed the Chromium-webbrowser under Linux-Mint 18 with the apt-package manager.

Later I downloaded a [64bit Chromium-build for linux](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/414992/) in a .zip-file. After I executed the containing binary "chrome", I recognized that the tray-icon is exactly the same icon used by my current theme for Chromium. So I tried to change the icon with the following .desktop-file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Chrome
Exec=MY/LOCAL/PATH/chrome
Icon=MY/LOCAL/PATH/testIcon.png
Terminal=false
```

The icon of the .desktop-file changed, but as I started the application I noticed that the tray-icon from the theme is used, instead of my desired icon.

How can this be? When I usually start a downloaded executable file a "default"-icon from the installed theme is used. How does the icon for the binary get found?
How can I use a custom tray-icon for my downloaded binary?

Thank you!